# Hide price and add to cart button, display a contact button in product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that looks great and hides the add to cart button on catalog page.

This is how it looks. I dont want the prices to display

[image]

---

I want this same button to display on the single product page with a custom link and without displaying price.

This is the single product page button that i want to change

[image]

---

Code I'm currently using

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("Escríbenos", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' .$button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To remove Add to Cart button on Single Product Page

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

To remove price

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

To add custom link as on your catalogs page

```
    function replacing_single_add_to_cart_button() {
   // Custom Link goes here    
 }

 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_single_add_to_cart_button', 30 );
```

I hope it helps.